# How do I do diff analysis across grouped records?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
#INPUT #DATE   #NAME   #VALUE
TEST1 20160620 AACT    203478480 
TEST2 20160621 AACT    203478480
```

I want to group it like so and have it split up by the NAME, I also need the date in there to append records for changes in the VALUE:

```
#NAME   DATE       VALUE
 AACT   20160602   186615450
        20160603   186615450
        20160604   186615450
        20160605   190045153
        20160606   186615450
        20160607   186615450
        20160608   160451251
        20160609   186615450
        201606010  186615450

 BAML   20160602   21900000
        20160603   21900000
        20160604   21900000
        20160605   21900000
        20160606   21900000
        20160607   21900000
        20160608   21900000
        20160609   12096251
        201606010  21900000
        201606011  21900000
        201606012  21900000
        201606013  21900000
        201606014  21900000
```

Basically I need to do a diff analysis per group, on the VALUE with the VALUE above it.  I've experimented with the following:

```
group3 = frame['VALUE'].groupby(frame['NAME'], sort = True)

for name, group in group3:
for diff in [elem for elem in group.diff() if elem > 0]:
        print (name, diff)
```

However, this does not give me the date for that record, it only gives me the NAME and the difference of the values.

I want my output to be like this:

```
('AACT', 20160605, 190045153)
('AACT', 20160608, 160451251)
('BAML', 20160609, 12096251)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How does your input dataframe given that group by? And what is the rule for "the group above it"?

Comment: Groupby is toward the bottom group3 = frame['VALUE'].groupby(frame['NAME'], sort = True), the input dataframe is only 2 lines of the full dataframe (for space purposes).